# May I declare the TypeScript Object base on the json format like this?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a java developer, I want to develop the Angular 6.0 now, I'm pretty new on the typescript. now I have a json string from the backend as below:

```
{  
   "test1":{  
      "aa":"7/22 – 7/28",
      "bb":"Tues July 24 11:15 - 22:20"
   },
   "test2":{  
      "aa":"7/22 – 7/28",
      "bb":"Tues July 24 11:15 - 22:20"
   }
}
```

How to declare the class Object?

for the java perspective, I will declare the class like this, I'm not sure whether it's right or not

```
export class Test{
    public aa: string;
    public bb: string;
}

export class Main{
    public test1: Test;
    public test2: Test;
}
```

Comment: that's not different from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class test {
  aa: string;
  bb: string;
}

class root {
 [key: string] : test;
}

const t: root = {
  'test2': { aa: 'hello', bb: 'world'},
  'test1': { aa: 'hello', bb: 'world'}
}
```

This also provides safety by raising an error at compile time when duplicate keys are found ie:

```
const t: root = {
  'test2': { aa: 'hello', bb: 'world'},
  'test1': { aa: 'hello', bb: 'world'},
  'test1': { aa: 'hello', bb: 'world'}
}
```

shows:

> Duplicate identifier ''test1''.

However, this may not fit in with your POJO's that you have shown.

Try it here
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20aa%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20bb%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20root%20%7B%0D%0A%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%20%3A%20test%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20t%3A%20root%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20'test2'%3A%20%7B%20aa%3A%20'hello'%2C%20bb%3A%20'world'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20'test1'%3A%20%7B%20aa%3A%20'hello'%2C%20bb%3A%20'world'%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20e%20%3D%20document.createElement('p')%3B%0D%0Ae.innerHTML%20%3D%20JSON.stringify(t)%3B%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(e)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

No, it should look something like this,

```
export interface Test1 {
    aa: string;
    bb: string;
}

export interface Test2 {
    aa: string;
    bb: string;
}
```

in order to verify you can just paste the JSON in **[`json2ts`](http://json2ts.com/)** and see the output.